# A characterization for $C_0(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ an open and bounded set. By definition
$$
C_0(\Omega) : \{ f \in C(\Omega) : A_{f, \epsilon} \text{ is compact} \text{ in } \Omega \forall \epsilon > 0\},
$$
where $A_{f, \epsilon} = : \{x \in \Omega : |f(x)| \geq \epsilon \}$. I'm trying to prove the identity (I don't know if it is true) :
$$
C_0(\Omega) = \{ f \in C({\Omega}) : \tilde{f} \text{ is continous}\}
$$
where
$$
\tilde{f} = 
\begin{cases}
f(x) , \text{ if } x \in \Omega \\ 0 , \text{ if }x \not\in \Omega
\end{cases}.
$$
**My attempt**: Let $f \in C_0(\Omega)$ and suppose that $\tilde{f}$ is not continous. Note that the discontinuity points of $\tilde{f}$ are on $\partial \Omega$.
So, there exists a $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$, a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset \Omega$ and an $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that
$$
|f(x_n)| \geq \epsilon_0.
$$
So, $x_n \in A_{\epsilon_0}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. The set $A_\epsilon$ is also comapct in $\mathbb{R}^N$, so,  it is sequentially compact. So, there exists an $x_0 \in A_{\epsilon_0}$ and a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ such that $x_{n_k} \rightarrow x_0$. By the continuity of  $f$ in $\Omega$ we get $f(x_{n_k}) \rightarrow f(x_0)$.

This is all I could think, but we get nothing from this. I don't know if what I'm trying to prove is really true or not. Any help to prove or disprove would be welcome. Maybe another caracterization would be good too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension

Comment: Why take a subsequence? You already meant (and should have written) that the $x_0\in\partial\Omega$ and $\{x_n\} \subset \Omega$ you chose were related by $x_n\to x_0.$ But then $x_0\in A_\epsilon,$ which contradicts $x_0\in\partial\Omega$ and you are done!

Comment: You are right Anne, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f \in C_0(\Omega)$, then the extension by zero $\tilde{f}$ is clearly continuous on $\Omega$. It is also continuous at each point $x \in \mathbb{R}^N \setminus \Omega$, as for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and $y$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}^N \setminus A_{f, \varepsilon}$ (which is a neighborhood of $x$), we have $f(y) \in (-\varepsilon , \varepsilon)$.

Conversely, let $f \in C(\Omega)$ be a function such that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous, and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $\tilde{f}$ is zero on the compact set $\partial \Omega$. So there is an open set $U \supset \partial \Omega$ such that $|\tilde{f}| \leq \varepsilon$ on $U$. Next we have $A_{f, \varepsilon} \subset \overline{\Omega} \setminus U$, i.e $A_{f, \varepsilon}$ is the closed subset of the compact set $\overline{\Omega} \setminus U$, so it is compact.